# Creating class hierarchy from text/xml file

Tags: python, oop, parsing

Lets say we have the following text file:

```
name                      | value
_________________________________
a.attribute_1             | val_0
a.b.attribute_2           | val_1
a.b.attribute_3           | val_2
a.c.attribute_4           | val_3
a.c.d.attribute_5         | val_4
a.e.f.g.attribute_6       | val_5
a.e.f.h.attribute_7       | val_6
```

Is there a way to parse the string under column 'name' to create hierarchal classes that will assign every attribute the corresponds val in which way that i can access all attributes and do basic operation like:

lets say `val_5 = 2` and `val_2 = 6`

```
sum = a.e.f.g.attribute_6 + a.b.attribute_3
```

and expect to get `sum = 8`.

What tools or generators i have to use ?

thank you.

Comment: Is the input trusted? Then you could use `eval`, at least on the `value` column.

Comment: I don't think you want a class hierarchy. Instead, just a dict `d1` that maps, for example, `"a.attribute_1"` to `"val_0"`, and another dict `d2` that, e.g, maps `"val_0"` to `2`. Then you can write `sum = d2[d1["a.e.f.g.attribute_6"]] + d2[d1["a.b.attribute_3]]`.

Comment: Final purpose is far more complex then just adding up the variables. therefore i do need a class hierarchy .